# Strange behavoir of recv function in winsock vc++

Tags: windows, visual-c++, winsock

I am using Asynchronous socket.

the server sends MSG to client continuously. client receives all the MSG but sometimes two or three messages at one time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is absolutely normal. Moreover, you are not guaranteed to read each time an integral number of your "messages". I mean, you may read 1.5 message (one and a half), then next time read 2.7 (the remaining half, two more, and a bit of the next), and so on.

**You** have to implement the logic that splits the stream into messages.